# node writeFileSync not writing to file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the command that is broken:

```
fs.writeFileSync('Metadata.json', metadataString);
console.log("Metadata written.");
```

I have placed a breakpoint and verified that metadataString is actually a string. The console logs `Metadata written` just fine and the file stays empty...

Not sure what else I can check... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete `Metadata.json` and see if `fs.writeFileSync()` is creating the file or not.

Answer (score 2):

`fs.writeFileSync()` throws an `Error` exception if it fails. Use a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    fs.writeFileSync('Metadata.json', metadataString);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error writing Metadata.json:' + err.message)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be seen on stdout anyway if his code fails?

Comment: My code have a try catch, it's not failing but it's not recording my files too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, `fs.writeFile` instead of `fs.writeFileSync` and it worked.
In your solution, it might be:

```
fs.writeFileSync('Metadata.json', metadataString, (err) => {
   if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `writeFileSync` for the same and pass your string and add `encoding:'utf8'` though it is default. And For Error Handling you can always put try catch block. Also put an `await` till your string data is loaded.(**In case If you are using a larger data set**)

```
try {
    let yourString = `{"HI":"This is Test Creating A File"}`;
    fs.writeFileSync(fileName, await yourString, { encoding: 'utf8' });
} catch (error) {
    console.log('File Creation Error',error);    
}
```

PS: Don't forget to  `import fs from 'fs';`